# Change username if you have a specific rank/role

Tags: discord.js

I want to make the bot constantly looking if any user has a rank and in case of finding a user with that role add an emoticon in front of the name

```
    client.on('ready', () => {

        if(!member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Prueba")){
            //Set the nickname
            member.setNickname(` ${nickname}`)
         }
    });
```

Comment: And? What's your problem?

Comment: I'm also sure that people will totally love that their display name is changed :)

Comment: The problem I have is that the bot does not modify the name of the people who have the rank "Prueba"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it right you want to change member nickname. In that case you must do `member` not `client`. And if you are using v12 you need to add `cache` before `find`

```js
//Check if member doesn't have the role
if(!member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Prueba")){
   //Set the nickname
   member.setNickname(` ${nickname}`)
}else{
  console.log(`${member.tag} has the role`)
}
```

Comment: The problem I have is that the bot does not modify the name of the people who have the rank "Prueba"

Comment: Are you sure bot can change nicknames ?

Comment: Since it was fine for me. Also make sure you DON'T have the role. I have also edited the code so it will now tell you if you have the role.